# Bug on new profile pages, 'type' is null or not an object in IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed

It appears the new profile pages and the use of jQuery 1.5.2 combined with IE8 (on Win7 here) are running into [this bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8755) which appears to have been fixed in later versions (1.6 and above).

The new profile page loads fine, but when clicking on most of the other links on the page, it throws a

> 'type' is null or not an object  jquery.min.js, line 16 character
>   26101

I don't really expect a fix to this any time soon as upgrading to 1.6 and beyond has other implications, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Always nice when a bug report already contains the solution. Thanks a lot!

Fixed in the next build.